# Appengine Go development server can't find the template package

Tags: google-app-engine, templates, go

I'm attempting to do the go appengine tutorial found [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/go/gettingstarted/), but I can't complete the example that imports the template library. This is the example code I am trying:

```
package hello

import (
    "fmt"
    "http"
    "template"
)

func init() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", root)
    http.HandleFunc("/sign", sign)
}

func root(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, guestbookForm)
}

const guestbookForm = `
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="/sign" method="post">
      <div><textarea name="content" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea></div>
      <div><input type="submit" value="Sign Guestbook"></div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
`

func sign(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    err := signTemplate.Execute(w, r.FormValue("content"))
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.String(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}

var signTemplate = template.MustParse(signTemplateHTML, nil)

const signTemplateHTML = `
<html>
  <body>
    <p>You wrote:</p>
    <pre>{@|html}</pre>
  </body>
</html>
`
```

The error I am receiving is:

```
Compile error:
    /home/habitue/Programming/GoExamples/hello/hello.go:36: undefined: template.MustParse
```

My app.yaml is this:

```
application: helloworld
version: 1
runtime: go
api_version: 3

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: _go_app
```

I've tried modifying the dev_appserver.py `EXTRA_PATHS` list to include the system version of Go's libraries, since I noticed the appengine lib folder did not include a template library, but to no avail. Here is my current `EXTRA_PATHS`with my changes being the last two entries:

```
EXTRA_PATHS = [
  DIR_PATH
  ,os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'antlr3')
  ,os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'django_0_96')
  ,os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'fancy_urllib')
  ,os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'ipaddr')
  ,os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'protorpc')
      ,os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'webob')
  ,os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'yaml', 'lib')
  ,os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'simplejson')
  ,os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'google.appengine._internal.graphy')
  ,os.path.join('usr', 'lib', 'go', 'lib')
  ,os.path.join('usr', 'lib', 'go', 'pkg', 'linux_amd64')
]
```

At this point, I'm not really sure how to proceed. I can't seem to find anywhere online that mentions a similar problem. I'm using the 64bit linux version of the appengine Go SDK, and my OS is Arch Linux, if that is any help.

Comment: For info, I've logged an issue covering this at http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=6075&q=r60&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The sample is outdated starting with the SDK 1.5.5 update.

Now it should look more or less like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "http"
    "template"
)

func init() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", root)
    http.HandleFunc("/sign", sign)
}

func root(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, guestbookForm)
}

const guestbookForm = `
<html>
 <body>
  <form action="/sign" method="post">
    <div><textarea name="content" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea></div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Sign Guestbook"></div>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
`

func sign(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    err := signTemplate.Execute(w, r.FormValue("content"))
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.String(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}

var signTemplate = template.Must(template.New("SignIn").Parse(signTemplateHTML))

const signTemplateHTML = `
<html>
 <body>
  <p>You wrote:</p>
  <pre>{{.|html}}</pre>
 </body>
</html>`
```

Notice the difference in call initializing `var signTemplate` and the template parameter in the signTemplateHTML variable, `{{.|html}}` instead of `{@|html}`.

Answer (score 1):

The Go [template package](http://golang.org/pkg/template/) has recently been rewritten. Try importing `"old/template"`.

[2011-08-17 (base for r60)](http://golang.org/doc/devel/weekly.html#2011-08-17)

> This weekly contains some package re-shuffling. Users of the http and
>   template packages may be affected.
>
> This weekly replaces the template package with exp/template. The
>   original template package is still available as old/template. The
>   old/template package is deprecated and will be removed at some point
>   in the future. The Go tree has been updated to use the new template
>   package. We encourage users of the old template package to switch to
>   the new one. Code that uses template or exp/template will need to
>   change its import lines to "old/template" or "template", respectively.

Comment: Yet it could be a good idea to try to use the new template package, as the answer below shows. So the options are: a) import "old/template" or b) import "template" (but ignore the outdated tutorial and use the answer below for SDK 1.5.5).